# How to use CalendarExtender with Scripmanager (not ToolkitScriptManager)

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

I'm using VS 2012 with AjaxControlToolkit (for 4.0). here my source code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SoTNMTApplication.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="GlobalSite/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"></asp:CalendarExtender>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CalendarExtender not working

it's only work with *ToolkitScriptManager*.

How to use CalendarExtender with Scripmanager (not ToolkitScriptManager)

Answer (score 0):

Using ToolkitScriptManager will help, its actually better than ScriptManager and has all the functionality of ToolkitScriptManager.